# Retrieve all last points/records per tag in InfluxDB, without WHERE clause

Tags: sql, influxdb, influxql

I have roughly 1500 devices which, at random frequencies, push data to my InfluxDB v1.8+ instance. I am looking for the most efficient way, at least in terms of performance, to collect the last point for each device_id (tag).

For the sake of brevity the data in this measurement it quite simple:

```
time, device_id (tag), usage (in bytes)
1593514228321002500, 'A12345', 32212254720
```

I am guaranteed that each and every point has the 'usage' field populated. That is not a concern. So having the latest point, for each tag (device_id), with a timestamp is actually what I want.

My current solution, which is far from scalable nor efficient, is listing all device_id's first:

```
$ show tag values on "my_database" with key = "device_id"
```

... and then iterate through each to get the last point:

```
$ select time, device_id, usage
    from @measurement
    where device_id = '@device_id'
    order by time desc
    limit 1
```

My question: how can I most efficiently fetch the last points/records **for all device_ids (tag)**, without providing a WHERE clause on device_id? Preferably in one command, so I can remove the foreach iteration.

The same question has been asked for other flavours, [for example here in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql). This question is specific to InfluxDB.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. Use `last()` for any of the one field.

```
select last(usage), * from @measurement group by device_id;
```

Comment: Thanks @Sheeram K., but that is still with a device_id predicate. The question is: how to get it for **all devices**, e.g. not having to provide a device_id?

Comment: Try `select last(usage), * from @measurement group by device_id`. And optionally add `where time > ...`  to limit time range.

Comment: Ok. I thought you need for a specific device_id. Let me edit my ans.

Comment: @YuriLachin That's it! Very good point with the `where time`-clause. If you'll write it up as an answer, I'd gladly accept it.